# Use variable as -path when using Get-Content on PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I am trying to get a content of a text file by using Get-Content and I want the value for the -path to be on a variable like so:

```
$MyFileName = "testfile"    
$MyFilePath = "(.\MyFolder\" + $MyFileName + ".txt)"
$ServerList = Get-Content -Path $MyFilePath
```

But I keep getting the error:

```
Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is null.
```

It works if I hard code the file path

```
$ServerList = Get-Content -Path (.\MyFolder\MyFile.txt)

Write-Host $MyFilePath
.\MyFolder\testfile.txt
```

Comment: Don't use parentheses in the filename unless the files literally contain them. `-Path` expects a string or string array. In your case, that would be `-Path '.\MyFolder\MyFile.txt'`.

Comment: tried removing them, still the same

Comment: please, unless you NEED the parens around your Get-Content section, **_remove them_**. they are unusual enuf that they are distracting from the newly changed point of your question. if you _do_ need them, please explain why.

Comment: I don't specifically need them, I am new at powershell and I basically come up with this code from various sources, i'll update my question once i get home

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that the issue is on using a variable inside a workflow. I was so focused on that block of code that I forgot to look at the bigger picture.

I have the code below which had the issue:

```
Workflow GetServerStatus{
   $ServerList = Get-Content -path $FullFileName
   $ServiceList = Get-Content service_list.txt
   ForEach -Parallel ($Server in $ServerList){
      InlineScript{
         Get-Service -ComputerName $Using:Server -name $Using:ServiceList
      }
   }
}

#credits to @Lee_Dailey
$Extension = 'txt'
$FileName = $BaseName, $Extension -join '.'
$Directory = '.\server'
$FullFileName = Join-Path -Path $Directory -ChildPath $FileName

GetServiceStatus
```

It turns out that the issue is that I am not passing the variables correctly to a workflow
It should be:

```
Workflow GetServiceStatus{
    param(
        $FullFileName
    )
```

It is then called like so

```
GetServiceStatus $FullFileName
```

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the variable, the string literally has parentheses in it:

```
$MyFileName = "testfile"
$MyFilePath = "(.\MyFolder\" + $MyFileName + ".txt)"
$myfilepath

(.\MyFolder\testfile.txt)
```

This would work:

```
$MyFileName = "testfile"
$MyFilePath = ".\MyFolder\" + $MyFileName + ".txt"
$myfilepath

.\MyFolder\testfile.txt
```

You could put the parentheses on the outside, but you don't need to.  Or

```
".\MyFolder\$MyFileName.txt"
```

Answer (score 1):

try setting the full file path like

```
$MyFilePath = "C:\My Folder\My File.txt"
```

or if you the relative path is really what you want remove the brackets like

```
$MyFilePath = ".\My Folder\My File.txt"
```

Comment: tried it, i still get the same error. I edited my question because the actual filename is a variable in itself minus the file extension .txt

Comment: try using `Join-Path` like `$MyFilePath = Join-Path -Path "C:\My Folder" -ChildPath $MyFileName` if the filetype is missing add this line `$MyFilePath += '.txt'`

Comment: still the same, i even tried $MyFilePath = "C:\My Folder\{0}.txt" -f $MyFileName
i get the correct result when I write-host $MyFilePath. The issue is when using the $MyFilePath variable for the -Path option on Get-Content

Comment: so what is `$MyFileName` really? what does `$MyFileName | Get-Member` return?

Comment: TypeName: System.String

Comment: and what is the value of the string? what does `Test-Path $MyFilePath` return?

Answer (score 1):

here's one way to do what you seem to want. [*grin*] the 1st part is your code with the very peculiar resulting file name. the 2nd part is broken out into parts that are easier to read/understand/modify.

```
$YourFileName = "testfile"    
$YourFilePath = "(.\MyFolder\" + $YourFileName + ".txt)"

$BaseName = 'testfile'
$Extension = 'txt'
$FileName = $FileName, $Extension -join '.'
$Directory = $env:TEMP
$FullFileName = Join-Path -Path $Directory -ChildPath $FileName

$YourFilePath
$FullFileName
```

output ...

```
(.\MyFolder\testfile.txt)
C:\Temp\testfile.txt
```

note that your code made a file name that is almost certainly invalid. [*grin*]

Comment: I think the issue stems from me using Get-Content inside a Workflow for parallel processing, when I take the code outside of the workflow, it worked flawlessly. I thought the issue was just with that block of code but I was mistaken, I will update my question.

Comment: @Ruben_PH - ah! that changes things a good deal. as long as you fix that horribly broken file name maker code, folks can focus on other aspects. [*grin*]